# To update my layout elements continuously in an event method from inside the event method using loops

Tags: java, javafx, logic

I am trying to build an analog stopwatch. There is a button that when I click, the stopwatch starts counting in seconds.

Note that this code runs okay (technically) but there is something wrong in terms of my "java language"-based logic or/and my thinking-based logic. Also I know that my stop watch would have some marginal error within milli seconds. There are two print out statements that can check my logic. Note that I have some C coding experience but new to this. ***EDIT: The platform is javaFX***

Now, I am facing 3 problems with this code.

**The three problems technically written:**

1- The second print out statement's output is same as the first one's. i.e, my IF statement is not working since temp + 1 is still equal to the current number of seconds although this is impossible if we consider the fact that the lines of codes, between them, are executed faster. **UPDATE: THIS, (1),  IS SOLVED.**

2- Ignoring problem (1), my image does not rotate although it should have since the IF statement is executed. Note that I am using stackpane and I added that image to my layout but it just sticks at 0 degrees and is not doing any thing.

3- The While loop itself is not working either even if I wait too much of time. I am not sure if it is "okay" or not to use a while loop inside an event handling method.

**The three problems structurally written:**

1-  N/A

2- Would it be possible for me to update my layout elements continuously in an event method from inside the even method using loops and not by using the button or something else?

3- Same as (2)

```
          btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            int temp = 0;
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            System.out.println("Seconds in current minute = " + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));

            temp = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            int temp2 = temp + 60;
            int counter = 1;

            do {
                System.out.println("Seconds in current minute = " + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                if ((temp + 1) == calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)) {
                    System.out.println("Seconds in current minute = " + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                    imageHolder2.rotateProperty().set(6.0 * counter);
                    counter++;
                    temp = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                }

            } while (temp2 != (calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) + 60));
        }
    });
```

Comment: 'I am not sure if it is "okay" or not to use a while loop inside an event handling method.'  That sounds like a bad idea. You might want to look into `SwingWorker`.

Comment: @bradimus `SwingWorker` will not be any use at all in a JavaFX Application. They are two different toolkits that use different UI threads.

Comment: @bradimus @ James it is my fault that I did not indicate that I am working with javaFX.

Comment: @James_D You are correct. I didn't read the code carefully enough.

Comment: I just went by the tags :). But I guess it isn't clear without reading the code pretty carefully...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I think you are just seeing the first `System.out.println(...)` (from before the loop) and the first one in the loop, which will produce the same output (except in the very rare (a few occurrences per million runs?) circumstance that the seconds "tick over" during execution of the three lines of code in between).

2) This is the real issue. Your loop is running (busily) in the FX Application Thread (because it is invoked by an event handler). This is the same thread that is used to update the UI and process events. Because you are keeping this thread busy, it will not have any opportunity to update the UI until your loop finishes. You need to either execute this loop in a background thread, and schedule the UI updates on the FX Application Thread, or (much much easier) use the animation API to do this.

3) You have a bunch of bugs in your logic. (1) You assign `calendar` before you start the loop, and never update it; so it will always represent the instant the handler starts. (2) You assign `temp2` to be `seconds + 60` and then your loop condition is `temp2 != seconds + 60`, which obviously is false, so the loop exits. Even if you update `calendar` on the loop iteration, it is extremely unlikely the `seconds` field changes in during the first iteration of the loop, so you will almost certainly exit the loop immediately. (3) If you update `calendar`, the `seconds` field will always be a value between 0 and 59 (inclusive), i.e. it will "wrap" at 60. `temp2` will always be at least 60, so once you fix bugs (1) and (2) your loop will never exit... (4) `if (temp + 1 == calendar.get(Calendar.SECONDS))` will fail when the minutes tick over, because `60 != 0`, so your iteration will stop as soon as that happens.

You can use a [`Timeline`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) to do this:

```
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
        // key frame that updates rotation on each second:
        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> {
            imageHolder2.setRotate(imageHolder2.getRotate() + 6);
            System.out.println("Seconds in current minute = " + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND));
        })
    );
    // repeat 60 times:
    timeline.setCycleCount(60);
    timeline.play();
}
```

If you want to use your original code, you need to wrap it in a background thread, and schedule the UI updates on the FX Application Thread. As noted above, there are multiple other bugs in your code. Here is a version with the logic fixed:

```
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
                int temp = 0;
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                System.out.println("Seconds in current minute = " + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));

                temp = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                int counter = 1;

                do {
                    calendar = Calendar.getInstance() ;
                    if (temp != calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)) {
                        System.out.println("Seconds in current minute = " + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                        double rotation = 6.0 * counter ;
                        Platform.runLater(() -> imageHolder2.rotateProperty().set(rotation) );
                        counter++;
                        temp = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                    }

                } while (counter <= 60);
            });

            thread.setDaemon(true);
            thread.start();
        }
```

Finally, note you can also just do this:

```
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    RotateTransition animation = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(60), imageHolder2);
    animation.setByAngle(360);
    animation.play();
}
```

Comment: Oh I guess for (1), you are correct. I did not notice there is one inside the loop and (at the same time) outside the IF statement.

Comment: It shows a red exclamation mark besides " Platform.runLater(() -> imageHolder2.rotateProperty().set(6.0 * counter));". it says that "local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final. While I am trying to understand  "lambda" operations stuff, it would be very helpful if you can tell what it is going on with the error.

Comment: Yes, sorry; I fixed that in an update. It just means exactly what it says: local variables accessed in a lambda expression (`counter` in this example) must be final or effectively final, i.e. they must be assigned a value only once (not modified). Since `counter++` modifies the variable, you can't use it in a lambda. But it really is overkill to use a thread for this anyway; just use the animation API.

Comment: Sorry i just saw your comment. Ignore my last comment

Comment: Your Animation-based code works pretty well. My while-based code was really a mess such that when I made the while runs successfully, the calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) always gives the same number till  I click the button. So idk what it is going on (it is really a mess).

Comment: I think I addressed that: you never update `calendar`.

Comment: Okay. What if I want to stope the while loop by the "occurance" of another event... in the "fixed" while loop code... instead of  stopping at 60 seconds? Is it possible to make a "return" statement for an event in javaFX so that I can use as a condition in the while loop? For example: Click 
"stop" or "reset" ?

Comment: Okay. After spending hours with the "fixed" code, it brought me a headache. For your code, I want to stop the Animation by a total different event (another button)... how to link the two events?

Comment: That sounds like a different question; but I don't really see the problem. You just have to keep a reference to the `Animation`, so you can call `stop()` (or `pause()` on ti.